# Question related to combinations and sequences.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm not the best when it comes to math, and wondered if anyone here were interested in helping me with a problem?

The problem is the following:

You have 10 boxes lined up on a row, like this:

[x] [x] [x] [x] [x] [x] [x] [x] [x] [x]

Each of the 10 boxes is to be filled with either of the numbers 1, 2 or 3.
Like in this example:

[3] [1] [3] [2] [2] [1] [3] [3] [1] [1]

How many different combinations or variations of numbers inside the boxes exist?

I would prefer both an explanation as well as a concrete answer to the problem.
Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried doing just two boxes by hand?  Do you consider $[3][1]$ different from $[1][3]$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please include some of your own attempts at solving the problem, so we know where you are stuck and need help.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes. [3][1] and [1][3] are to be considered two different combinations in this problem. If i'm not mistaken there are 9 possible scenarios if there were only 2 boxes.

Comment: That is correct.  Now you should be able to generalize to $n$ boxes.  You have three choices for the first, for each one you have three choices for the second, and ...

Comment: @RossMillikan If done with 3 boxes the answer becomes 27 - So 10 boxes is 3^10?

Comment: Exactly right. $\ \ $

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

IF each box has $\huge \color{blue}{s}$ states,
then the total possible arrangements for $\huge \color{purple}{n}$ boxes would be
$$\huge \color{blue}{s}\times \color{blue}{s}\times \cdots  (\color{purple}{n}\text{ times}) = \color{blue}{s}^{\color{purple}{n}}$$

Comment: Ofcourse assuming that order matters here and repetitions are allowed!

Comment: Haha true! $3$ states and $10$ boxes require repetitions for sure

Comment: That is right, repetitions are allowed. Were does the 8 come from? Doesn't each box only have 3 states?

Comment: Ahh yes you're right! thats supposed to look like small case $\color{blue}{S}$, you may replace it with $3$.. let me see if I can make it look better :)

Comment: That's better! So the answer is 3^10 = ca.60000?

Comment: $3^{10}$ looks perfect!

Comment: I tried putting it like that, but couldn't get the hang of the formatting. Thank you! :)